# $request->getPost() returns empty in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have a form setup in codeigniter 4 with 2 routes.

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->post('/', 'Home::index');
```

But when I am retrieving the form values using the below code, it always returns empty array.

```
$this->request->getPost()
```

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();
var_dump($request->getPost()); die;
```

My form has multiple file attachments. When I try to retrieve the data, it always give empty array. Can anyone help me out to fix this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1SLS.png)

Comment: How big are the files you are uploading? Make sure you are not breaking any of the limits set via the PHP configuration, like `post_max_size` for example.

Comment: Files don't come in the post. They are delivered via the `$_FILES` array to your backend. Also have you set the correct enctype on your form? `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: It was POST_MAX_FILES. It was set as 2 and files were more than 5. I have fixed that.